# Using functional language concepts with OO - is there a language?

Tags: language-agnostic, functional-programming, oop

I was recently thinking how I'm not always using the beautiful concepts of OO when writing Pythonic programs. In particular, I thought I'd be interested in seeing a language where I could write the typical web script as

```
# Fictional language 
# This script's combined effect is to transform (Template, URI, Database) -> HTTPOutput

HTTPOutput: 
    HTTPHeaders + Maintext

Flags:                              # This is a transform URI -> Flags 
    value = URI.split('?').after
    refresh = 'r' in value
    sort = /sort=([a-z])/.search(value)

HTTPHeaders:                       # This is a transform Flags -> HTTPHeaders
    'Content-type:...' +  Flags.refresh ? 'Refresh: ...' : ''

Maintext:
    Template.replace('$questions', PresentedQuestions [:20] )

Questions:
    (Flags.sort = 'r') ? RecentQuestions : TopQuestions 

PresentedQuestions:
    Questions % '<h4>{title}</h4><p>{body}</p>'

RecentQuestions:
    Database.Questions . sort('date')  

TopQuestions:
    Database.Questions . sort('votes')
```

See what happens? I am trying to make as many objects as possible; each paragraph declares something I call *transform*. For example, there is a transform `HTTPHeaders`. In an imperative language that would be a declaration of class, object and function combined:

```
class HTTPHeaders_class
{
     public char* value
     HTTPHeaders_class() 
     {
         value = ... + Flags.refresh ? + ... // [1] 
     }

}

class Flags_class 
{
     public char* flagstring;
     public bool refresh;
     ...
     Flags_class() 
     {
         value = ... /* [3] */ 
         refresh = ...
     }
}

Flags = new Flags_class (URI)
HTTPHeaders = new HTTPHeaders_class (Flags)   // [2]
```

However, I want to have **no way to specify that an object should change** unless the inputs from which the objects is made change; and no way to have side effects. This makes for a drastic simplification of language. I believe this means we're doing a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) ("a programming paradigm that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids state and mutable data").

I certainly try to use things like Python classes, M-V-C framework and Django (thanks to the answer), but I don't think they have the concepts above and below.

1. Each object has a `value` field that can be referred just by writing the class name.
2. If `HTTPHeader` is referred somewhere, this means that a static, unchangeable object `HTTPHeader` is created as soon as possible. All references to `HTTPHeader` then refer to this object.
3. Suppose I want to repeat the program with the same `URI` object while the interpreter is still in memory. Since `Flags` depends only on `URI` and `HTTPHeaders` only on `Flags`, those are not recalculated. However, if `Database` is modified, then `Questions` need to be recalculated, and thus the `HTTPOutput` may change too.
4. The interpreter automatically deduces the correct sequence of initializing the classes. Their dependency must form a tree for that to happen, of course.

I believe this will be a useful models for programs like web scripts where there are no side effects. Is there a useful language where one writes program similar to this already?

Comment: About 'functional programming' tag: the way I understand it, functional programming is a type of declarative programming where you break the program into functions describing how to transform things without side effects and states, which is exactly what I want to do, with the exception that I want to cache the results of intermediate calculations for the future use.

Comment: Caching the result of intermediate calculations is not considered a side-effect or state in pure functional programming; you still get the same answer every time you call a function with the same arguments, regardless of whether it was a freshly calculated or cached value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to delve into web application development with Python, then look at [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). You are better off using a MVC architecture in this case and Django does a very nice job of supporting MVC applications.

What you are probably interested in is more of a [Declarative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) approach than a functional one. Functional programming is more concerned with mapping an input to an output as a pure (mathematical) function. The declarative approach is all about stating what should happen instead of how to do it.

In any case, dig into Model-View-Controller and Django. You will probably find that it fits the bill in a completely different manner.

Comment: Ye, Python classes and Django cover much of what I trying to say... Though I believe they are stateful?

Comment: You Django response is created by a function -- you can use any programming style you want for that function.  If you want stateless FP-style transforms, that can be made to work.

Comment: Yes, but if I am a function and the compiler doesn't know I am pure, he won't know that I am thread-safe and cacheable.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29).  It is specifically designed as a functional language (based on [OCaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml)) with OO support utilizing the .NET stack.

Comment: Interesting, though not purely functional.

Comment: I think you're being a little too picky. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly what you are looking for but [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) tries to integrate OO and functional features under a common language.

Comment: Scala covers such a wide range of language features that I'd be really surprised if you didn't find the language features you want--but possibly not a framework you find acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like a DSL for web applications and Sinatra is such a DSL. Sinatra does not do exactly what you do there but it's in the same ballpark. http://www.sinatrarb.com/ - it's written in Ruby but hey, let's all be friends here in dynamic languages land.

Comment: I'm all for Ruby, just don't know it yet :)

Answer (score 1):

This actually feels very much like Haskell, except that you're not using pure functions here. For example, `Flags` doesn't have the URI passed into it; `URI` is a separate definition that is presumably not producing the same URI every time it's called, and so on.

For `URI` to be a pure function, it would have to have a parameter that would give it the current request, so that it can always return the same value for the same inputs. (Without any parameters to work on, a pure function can only return the same result over the life of a closure.) However, if you want to avoid explicitly giving `URI` a parameter every time, this can be done with various techniques; we do this with monads in Haskell.

It seems to me that the style of programming you're thinking of might be based on "combinators," having small functions that are glued together inside a framework to produce a large, complex function that does the overall processing.

Comment: URI could be function but my language would automatically cache its value the first tie its called and never recalculate it again!

Comment: That's called memoization, and is indeed a common technique in many languages. I expanded the answer a bit to talk about pure functions in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I see my favourite language has not been mentioned yet, so I'd like to jump in and suggest [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com) as a language for 100% function programming. APL has a looong history and was developed when there was no Internet - but Dyalog is the most active provider of APL-Implementations and they also have a fully function [webserver](http://miserver.dyalog.com) that is available free of charge. (The interpreter is also available free of charge for non-commercial use.)